# orderlist primefaces doesn't display the data

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is first time when I am trying to use primefaces orderList component.
I try to add some values in it. I am inserting values but the orderList component doesn't display anything.

Here is how my page looks:
[image]

Before using this component, I used a selectManyListBox which displays the data. And looking with the chrome's developer tools, the code is the same:

[image]

The code of orderList is:

```
<p:orderList id="choices" value="#{questionnaireExtendedKeyAttribute.extendedKeyAttributeChoices}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.text}" itemValue="#{item.code}" controlsLocation="left" responsive="true">
    <f:facet name="caption">Available</f:facet>
</p:orderList>
```

and the code for selectOneListBox is:

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="choices1" size="10" styleClass="form-control input-sm" style="float: left;" readonly="#{not questionnaireExtendedKeyAttribute.templateSessionData.notPublished}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{questionnaireExtendedKeyAttribute.extendedKeyAttributeChoices}"/>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

For the orderList I was looking [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/orderList.xhtml)

Could you tell me where the problem is?

Comment: [mcve] please!!! and version info

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the link, that you shared, you have to define columns for oderList. In your case:

```
<p:column>
  <h:outputText value="#{item.text}" />
</p:column>
```

Comment: I did it before but it doesn't work. No data displayed.

Comment: Does your class of "item" have the attributes 'text' and 'code'? 
If these are selectitems, it should be 'label' and 'value'. 
Any log errors?

Comment: It has 'text' and 'code'. The returned type of getExtendedKeyAttributeChoices() is List<ListItemElement>

Comment: I have changed it to return List<SelectItem> but nothing displayed

Comment: It should work if ListItemElement has public getter methods for text and code attribute.. Are you sure about these? Don't you get any errors in log file?